# How can I access a class that is inherited from monobehaviour

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, monodevelop

My problem is a bit more complicated than the title:
I've got a GUIController class, which controls the GUI and I want to create an in-game buy menu. In this menu I can choose from weapons and I can buy them if I've got enough money. I have to access their data, like price, description or name.

Problems:
-To access their data, I have to instantiate an object from the class (start function has to run before accessing the data).
-The main Weapon class is inherited from MonoBehaviour, so I can't instantiate an object from the class.

Possible solution:
-I could instantiate a gameobject which contains the class as a script component and then I could access its data. I think it's not a nice solution though.

Question:
Should I store the information somewhere else? In a local db or something? I thought storing the information inside the class is a good idea, but I'm not that sure anymore.

Thank you for your answers in advance!

Comment: can you show the Class Structure..?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Given your class hierarchy the static variable suggestion clearly won't work. Edited to give another possible solution.

You could create a new class for `Weapon` properties and make instances of it for each weapon type. These could be populated from code, a database, config files, etc. When constructing an instance of a specific `Weapon` you could give it the properties object and copy across the values of all properties. This could be done using reflection to save you having to write an assignment for each property.

The weapon properties objects could be made and accessed in many ways. One suggestion would be to have a repository which could be used to get a reference to the object (if they are singletons) or return a new one.

Incidentally, this is quite a broad question and the 'correct' answer may depend on how much data you have and how you intend to use it, or may be a matter of best practice. As such it's possibly better suited for [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [gamedev.stackexchange.com](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Class hierarchy looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/t9BRHsr.jpg
I set the price in the Start function of the USP class for example,. Since the Price member is declared in the Weapon class, I can't set it to static.